# Need to dump yuv frames from mp4 file

Tags: gstreamer

I dumped JPEG frame using below command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=<FILE LOCATION>! qtdemux name=demux  demux.video_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! multifilesink location=frame%d.yuv
```

JPEG image is displaying fine.

When I am trying to dump YUV frames from mp4 file using below command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=[FILE LOCATION] ! qtdemux name=demux  demux.video_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! multifilesink location=frame%d.yuv
```

I am not able to see the image as the dumped frame is without header detail(Width&Height).

After converting this frame to ppm format using below command:

```
yuvtoppm [WIDTH] [HEIGHT] frame1.yuv > frame1.ppm
```

I am able to see the frame, but it is not in YUV format.

Answer (score 0):

So what is your expectation? Raw YUV by definition come with no header - they are raw. Usually applications reading these files require you to set width, height and format as yuvtoppm does.

You may want to check out `y4menc` which probably adds a header to these files that *some* applications may be able to read.

Or you can store it as video files - `matroskamux` and `avimux` should be able to handle uncompressed data.

Comment: I want the captured frame in this format: Netpbm image data, size = W x H, rawbits, greymap